# Excel formula not updated automatically after adding sheet with the name that formula expects - how to fix it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have excel workbook (with vba procedures in it) with 3 tabs - lets call it Control model.

Each of the tab in Control model have formulas that are linked to the various sheet names that are not present in the Control model but are on other excel output (Input data -which has 7 sheets). The formulas  in 3 tabs of Control model are holding sheet names of those present in Input data.

My Control model creates output (new excel book) that inserts 3 tabs from control model (with formulas referencing to sheet names of Input data) and Input data file. So I have a final file with 10 sheets in it ,however my formulas in 3 tabs from Control model will not update until I actually go to a specific cell and click after last element of formula and press enter.

Is there a way of fixing it with VBA or it is just inner excel characteristic that formula will not work if it reference to data that is not present in the same workbook at the time of formula creation?

Comment: Its a bit difficult to understand what is updating and what is not without seeing some screenshots or samples. It may be that Excel doesn't know that the the formulae has to be recalculated. Do you use a UDF (VBA function) inside the cells? Try including application.volatile in the UDF. Otherwise try a force recalculate from VBA or a Data > Refresh all. I think Excel does an auto update from linked workbooks if the are open. If they are closed, a "refresh all" (CTRL+ALT+F5) should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Super User please [Edit] your post & share some sample data along with the formula you need to be supported by the VBA,,, since the text you have written is not enough to realize the execution!!

Comment: Did you check the new table name under Name Manger?